# Geometry package - too much space on bottom

Tags: geometry

I have an inflexible formatting requirement from my publisher for typesetting the text area. Top, bottom, left, right margins must each be 2cms on an A4 paper. The text area includes all headers and footers. The geometry package - to my understanding - provides all functionality required for achieving the goal. However, in my MWE the bottom margin is just too large. I do not know why.

Highly appreciate your support!

```
 \documentclass[12pt]{scrbook}

 \usepackage[a4paper, left=2cm, right=2cm, top=2cm, bottom=2cm, includeheadfoot]{geometry}

 \usepackage{scrpage2}
 \pagestyle{scrheadings}
 \clearscrheadfoot
 \rehead{\headmark}
 \lehead{\pagemark}
 \lohead{\headmark}
 \rohead{\pagemark}

 \usepackage{lipsum}

 \begin{document}
 \section{test}
 \lipsum[1]
 \lipsum[1]
 \lipsum[1]
 \lipsum[1]\footnote{test}
 \lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Use the `showframe` option in `geometry`, so you can see it better. Also, you can control the space for footer with  `foot=1cm`, for example.

Comment: Your foot is empty, but if you add something with e.g. `\ofoot{yyyyyyyyyyXXXXXXXX}` the spacing looks okay.

Comment: Or (a variation of Ulrike's suggestion) use `includehead` instead of `includeheadfoot` if you really don't need the footer.

Comment: Thanks for the quick comments. I set foot=0cm. :-) Also, I really like the showframe option to understand the geometry package better. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

If there should be no space for footer add `nofoot` to the options of package `geometry`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrbook}

\usepackage[
  margin=2cm,% each margin should be 2cm
  includeheadfoot,% text area includes header
  nofoot,% no space for footer
  %showframe% show the page layout
]{geometry}

\usepackage[automark]{scrpage2}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearscrheadfoot
\ohead{\pagemark}
\ihead{\headmark}

\usepackage{lipsum}% only for dummy text

\begin{document}
\chapter{Foo}
\lipsum[1-6]
\section{test}
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]\footnote{test}
\lipsum[2-20]
\end{document}
```

Result with option `showframe`:

[image]

---

Of topic: Note that package `scrpage2` is outdated since 2014. Its successor is `scrlayer-scrpage`:

```
\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}% sets pagestyle scrheadings automatically
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ohead{\pagemark}
\ihead{\headmark}
```